# How to view (only) the message, not the message source, in external command with (neo)mutt

Tags: mutt

I want to view some mails in external commands, like `less` or `vim`, but when I do something like the following

`macro index   <f6> "|less -\n" "view with less"`

then the whole mail source will be displayed in the external command which is (at least for me) too much. Can I only pipe the content (neo)mutt would display to external commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the `pipe_decode` option, Mutt will decode the message if necessary, and also weed headers so that only the headers that you would ordinarily see in the pager would be piped to whatever command you use.

From the Mutt manual on my system:

```
3.208. pipe_decode

   Type: boolean
   Default: no

   Used in connection with the <pipe-message> command. When unset, Mutt
   will pipe the messages without any preprocessing. When set, Mutt will
   weed headers and will attempt to decode the messages first.
```

(also available here: http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#pipe-decode)